# JMeter cookie data incomplete details

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I think my HTTP request has incomplete cookies in it.

As per fiddler below is the cookie data:

`Cookie: JSESSIONID=B991823B0DD178BB5ASDF5ASDFB44864; Session=sessionid=A05C2B8F808CADBB7F0032CEA430D67C.uatnode1&ipaddress=122.1xx.1xx.1x`

`SAMLResponse=PD94***********************************************`

As per JMeter:

`POST https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx//xxx......
POST data:SAMLResponse=PD94..................
Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=B991823B0DD178BB5ASDF5ASDFB44864`

I do not see the session id details here.

Can anyone please help he solve this issue?

Comment: Did you add HTTP cookie manager?

Comment: Yes i have added HTTP cookie manager

Comment: @ShravanMuni Please add complete snapshot of JMeter POST. Thanks!